# Insert large volume of data to create a tree with 25k nodes

Tags: javascript, sql-server-2005, tree

We are creating a tree structure with the help of a custom tool develop in JavaScript/Jquery. 
It works great now we have to create that tree with help of a feed file (CSV file).
I am working on creating a POC to understand the behavior of JS file for 25k nodes.
The problem is how do I Insert such volume of data  in my Database to check the behavior in browser.

Let me brief you about our approach for inserting the tree in the DB . We create the Left right value using the
NSM model. then insert it in two table one with a collection of node names. Other with left right values and some other 
Attributes. So I need to Insert such volume of data at least ( 10K nodes) with left right values of it.

We supply a json object for rendering tree  on client side then recursively calling the function to redraw the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is not entirely clear, but whenever I need to insert a large amount of data into sql server I use BCP, especially since your data is in CSV format, it should be easy:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

Comment: I don't have that much records ready with me too. so can there be a utility that can create that much data with some inputs.